# How to convert RDD to DF in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new in spark. And I am trying to convert below RDD to dataframe but not succeed

val customerRDD = sc.textFile("file:///home/hduser/data//customer.txt") //custId,CustName,CustEmail,CustPhone
//1,ABC,abc@gmail.com,+199240242234

Here I am trying to use customerRDD.toDF() method but not working

Also I have tried with createDataFrame() method but not able to get the idea

Does anyone can help How can I convert RDD to DF here?

Thanks

Comment: did you import the Spark implicits? i.e. `import spark.implicits._`?

Comment: Yes I was trying to import but it was giving an error

Answer (score 2):

An odd way of doing things these days, but if you must use an RDD to read a file with a header, then
consult this https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-spark-rdd/spark-load-csv-file-into-rdd/ and note specifically:

- Skip the header of each file (can be seen)
- Extract the columns yourself via map (can be seen)

Look at this for creating DF from RDD with schema using Structs, see https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-spark-rdd/convert-spark-rdd-to-dataframe-dataset. You can

- create a schema programmatically for a DF from RDD via  `createDataFrame()`
- or use default schema with `implicits`